# Product of two time duration is zero in a Golang variable

Tags: time, go

It's weird in below Golang code that product of two time duration is zero in variable 'delay', but when print the product directly without through any variable, the output is as expected. Anyone can explain this?

```
 func StartCleanTask() {
  go func() {
       delay := cfg.Config.Timeout * time.Second
       for {
           fmt.Println("Go clean task: ", delay, cfg.Config.Timeout*time.Second)
           select {
           case <-time.After(cfg.Config.Timeout * time.Second):
               clean()
           }
     }
  }()
```

}

The output is:

```
 Go clean task: 0 5m0s
```

**Update:**

I also attempted to run following code, it works well.

```
package main 
import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {

   var timeout time.Duration
   timeout = 100
   delay := timeout * time.Second

   fmt.Println("Go clean task: ", delay, timeout*time.Second)

}
```

**Update again:**

Paul's answer is accepted. Actually StartCleanTask() is invoked in the init function of cfg package, and cfg.Config.Timeout is assigned to a specified value in main function. BUT I ignored that package's init() function is invoked implicitly before main(), so the variable delay is always ZERO.

BTW, I don't understand why some people give negative score to this question. I think others may hit similar problem, and this post should be helpful to the victim who don't really know the calling sequence between init() and main().

Comment: What is the type of cfg.Config.Timeout? Is it time.Duration?

Comment: It works in simple solution: https://play.golang.org/p/XScNTsD3yX

Comment: @PawełAdamski  Yes, its type is time.Druation:Timeout time.Duration

Comment: And are you updating cfg.Config.Timeout concurrently to this?

Comment: @PaulHankin  no, cfg.Config.Timeout is updated only once while reading value from a config file(json format).

Comment: @thinkhy and is it updated before or after you call StartCleanTask()? Can you include in your question how you're initializing it? Have you run your code using the race detector? (https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html)

Comment: We can only guess since you haven't provided us with a reproducible example: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you're updating `cfg.Config.Timeout` concurrently to this task. Perhaps like this:

```
func main() {
    StartCleanTask()
    cfg.Config.Timeout = 300
    ...
}
```

This introduces a race, and it happens that in the goroutine inside `StartCleanTask`, `delay` is assigned before the `Timeout` is initialized, and the `fmt.Println` happens after the initialization.

You can use the [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) to see if this is the problem.

Assuming that `cfg` is only initialized once, probably the right fix is to only start the cleanup task once the initialization has finished.

Comment: You are right. Actually StartCleanTask() is invoked in the init function of cfg package, and  cfg.Config.Timeout is assigned to a specified value in main function. BUT I ignored that package's init() function is invoked before main().  Really thanks!